# How can I disable future dates?

Tags: 8

I am developing a custom module, where I need to disable future dates in the date pop-up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by adding an attribute `max`

```
$form['date'] = [
  '#title' => $this->t('Date'),
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#attributes' => [
    'type' => 'date',
    'min' => '-25 years',
    'max' => 'now',
  ],
  '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
];
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/comment/61733#comment-61733

Answer (score -2):

```
$form['birthDate'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t("Birth Date"),
        '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
        '#date_year_range' => '-100:0',
        '#datepicker_options' => array('maxDate' => '-1 day' ),
        '#date_label_position' => 'invisible',  
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );
```

Comment: Why did you post the code here?

Comment: Can you expand on how this addresses the problem?  Thanks.